# Is it possible to provide a blacklist of filenames to tar to prevent those files from being added to the archive?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

Something along the lines of tar --blacklist='foo.bar foo.baz' -czvf foo.tar.gz ./*

such that any files named foo.bar or foo.baz in the current directory or subdirectories would be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--exclude`:

> --exclude=PATTERN
>
> exclude files, given as a PATTERN

Also relevant:

> --no-anchored
>
> patterns match after any `/' (default for exclusion)

(taken from [tar(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tar.1.html) man page)

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please try doing some research before asking here.

```
$ man tar | grep -A 2 exclude


--exclude=PATTERN
       exclude files, given as a PATTERN

 --exclude-backups
       exclude backup and lock files

 --exclude-caches
       exclude contents of directories containing CACHEDIR.TAG,

 --exclude-caches-all
       exclude directories containing CACHEDIR.TAG

 --exclude-caches-under
       exclude everything under directories containing
       CACHEDIR.TAG

 --exclude-tag=FILE
       exclude contents of directories containing FILE, except

 --exclude-tag-all=FILE
       exclude directories containing FILE

 --exclude-tag-under=FILE
       exclude everything under directories containing FILE

 --exclude-vcs
       exclude version control system directories

 -X, --exclude-from FILE
       exclude patterns listed in FILE
```